# Unity prefab changes don't appear on Source Tree

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 4.5.4 with SourceTree 1.7.2.
I made a prefab and add a script to it, then commit and push the prefab!

When my team members, pull it, he got only an empty prefab without script!

He told me I need to shutdown Unity before using Git, because,
Unity don't actully write data to file before it is shutdown!

Is it true? Or, if so why?
And, is there a way to commit every changes without Unity getting Closed!

Comment: No, you just have to save the project/scene after you made any changes if you want to check in those changes to external source control.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how Unity3D is written it might be even the operative system's file cache the one refusing to write.

I have had the same experience with Unity3D and the only thing I can say is that it's not a big deal. Usually you commit code that has a sense and a purpose and you write the purpose in the commit text. Unless you are an avid programmer, you usually only send a few times at day.

Also remember to keep `Library` outside. This might alleviate the problem. You can easily find a `.gitignore` for Unity3d, like [this](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore).